# In python, how to get original order of list or array or series after randomizing them using random() function?

Tags: python, random

I'm unable to get original order of list or array or series after randomizing them using random() function ? Please suggest some solution or different algorithm for the same.

Comment: there is no (sane) way. just keep a copy before modifying it.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is:

```
import random

listA = [1,2,3,4]
listB = listA.copy()
random.shuffle(listA)
print(listA, listB)
```

You can also randomize using index only. It's useful when you want to avoid the manipulation of data.

```
import random

listA = ['A','B','C','D']

idxs = [i for i in range(len(listA))]
random.shuffle(idxs)

listB = [listA[i] for i in idxs]

print(listA, listB)
```